# Prove that if $ a, b \in R, $ then $(a + b)^2 = a^2 + ab + ba + b^2.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

> Let $ R $ be a ring. Prove that if $ a, b \in R, $ then $(a + b)^2 = a^2 + ab + ba + b^2.$

Doesn't seem to be much to this beyond using the the left and right distribution properties:

> (i) $ a (b+c) = ab + ac$
>
> (ii) $(b + c) a = ba + ca $

So $(a + b)^2 = (a +b)(a+b) =
 a (a+b) + b (a+b)$ (by $(ii))$ and $a (a+b) + b (a+b) = aa + ab + ba + bb.$ (by $(i))$

Am I missing any details?

Comment: Seems fine to me.

Comment: Looks good. $\phantom{}$

Comment: I'm thinking that the only point to this exercise is to point out that since commutativity is not assumed, we don't get the usual $a^2+2ab+b^2$ we when calculate $(a+b)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is perfectly fine, missing no details.